# Put a parameter after url suffix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, redirect

Using htaccess or any other way how can I pass a parameter to end of url suffix

EX: I need all the `.html` to be `html?v=1`

I tried the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.html?v=1 [R]
```

But Its not working

Answer (score 0):

Check first that the query string does not already exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !v=1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.html?v=1 [R,L]
```